# Is it possible to have multiple EDMX sharing the same model?

Tags: entity-framework, mapping

I need to have 2 different database (for example Oracle and SQLite) in a project.
I tried to use the same CSDL part for both EDMX, but then both generate the entity classes and I have compile error.
Is it possible to map to the same model?

Comment: If the databases have the same structure, just connect a context to the database you need.

Comment: By 2 different database I mean Oracle and SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

You can't map to the same model because the model is generated by a code generator that handles one connection. I split my project into two, one for the application logic and one of project type "Class Library" (i.e. DLL) where I store the emdx. USing this method you can have access to multiple databases through different contexts, and and an added bonus, your code is more modular.